# Copy data from cell above in specific cell below

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, fill

I have a table with years above and i want to copy it to specific cells below:

[image]

I want in example to copy years in (H1; I1) to (H78; I78) by choosing H78 and use Ctrl+V as shortcut , etc... i dont want to fill all blank cells, just specific cells.
Thanks you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you not just then select H1 and I1, hit Ctrl + C, move H78 and hit enter?  That's how I read your requirement.

Comment: i have to repeat that process a thousand time, that is why i want to find out if there is any VBA code can make it faster, so far i only tumble with fill blank cells

Comment: Ok, but how do I know where you want to copy the values to?  Your question is lacking some information about what the outcome should look like.  You provided one example, what are the other 1000?  What's the logic for where the data should be copied to?

Comment: it is random and i want to paste value from above to cell i choose like in the question.
when i click and choose J80, then click short cut, and it will auto copy from (J1;K1) to (J80;K80) only (not copy and paste all the way to but only copy to (J80;K80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're playing with fire here but this should work for you ...

```
Private rngSelectedRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Cells(Target.Cells(1, 1).Row, rngSelectedRange.Cells(1, 1).Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        Set rngSelectedRange = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

... paste that code in the worksheet you want to apply this logic to like shown below.

[image: Paste Special]

To make it work, just copy one of the headers and then start clicking around.

To stop it from working, hit ESC and it will disable the Copy operation.

It could be made more advanced by allowing multiple rows at once but that hasn't been built in.

Comment: Thanks you for your help sir just a tiny thing that after a while looking from document to monitor i may make mistake like copy to the wrong cells with the wrong year, will you make the code to auto copy from row 1 to the cell i click into so that if i have mistakenly copy 2019 to 2020 it will show it out by the value then i could double check with document.

Comment: Have you tried it by chance?  It will only copy to the column you selected in your copy.  It won't copy across columns BUT, if your selections cross years, it won't know.  It's a generic piece of code, it's not checking for your headers.  So if you copy H1:I1 and then click into cell O67, it will copy to cells H67:I67, not column O.